# Adding a list of 20 items to successive cells of a row in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using Clarifai's API to get tags for images in a URL and then add those to an empty data frame. There are 20 tags returned from Clarifai and I want to store each URL with its tags in 1 row. So the first cell in the row would be the URL then every successive cell would contain one of the 20 items about that URL.

It would look, ideally, like this

```
  URL.             | tag 1 | tag 2 | ..... | tag 20 

www.tetURL.com     | Xyz   | abc    |...... | fgh
```

So far, I have got the URL and the tags received, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to store each tag in a successive cell of a row

```
df = pd.DataFrame().   #Need to append values to this DataFrame

test = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQVOCBtn_hZYXawqd_OPu6YkAM737TEiIabOe0X_CIvPtuPRei96C3gI1KjTlc1URek05nhBSiV&usqp=CAc'

print('running predictions for this url:\n', test,'\n')

response = workflow.predict_by_url(test)
    
pred_vals = response['results'][0]['outputs'][2]['data']['regions'][0]['data']['concepts']

vals_list = []
for vals in range(len(pred_vals)):
    concept_val = pred_vals[vals]  # dict containing the id, name and value 
#     print(concept_val['name'],':', concept_val['value'])
    vals_list.append(concept_val['name'])
#     print('')

print(vals_list)
```

These are the values of vals_list

```
['long-sleeve', 'top', 'colorblock', 'turtleneck', 'crewneck', 'sweatshirt', 't-shirt', 'graphic', 'stripes', 'mockneck', 'sweater', 'coat', 'shirt', 'knit', 'hoodie', 'fedora', 'leather', 'eyelet', 'scarf', 'windowpane']
```

I will appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you managed to build a dictionary with url as key and tags as values? If so, you may be able to use [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict):

```
info_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info, orient='index')
```

If you don't want urls as index add .reset_index():

```
info_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info, orient='index').reset_index()
```

Comment: hmmm. No I haven't tried creating a dictionary with URL as the key, but that's a good suggestion. I will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider using a wide format data frame of `tag#` structure and instead use a long format data frame of two columns for `url` and `tag`. Long format data scales better with efficiency (i.e,. what if there are less or more than 20 tags)? Also, it is much easier to work with long data in most analytical operations: aggregation, modeling, plotting, etc. With this approach, simply use `DataFrame` constructor to build two-column data set.

```
test = ('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQVOCBtn_hZYXaw'
        'qd_OPu6YkAM737TEiIabOe0X_CIvPtuPRei96C3gI1KjTlc1URek05nhBSiV&usqp=CAc')

print('running predictions for this url:\n', test,'\n')

response = workflow.predict_by_url(test)     
pred_vals = (response['results'][0]['outputs'][2]
             ['data']['regions'][0]['data']['concepts'])

vals_list = []
for concept_val in pred_vals:
    vals_list.append(concept_val['name'])

# TWENTY-ROW DATA FRAME WITH SAME URL FOR EACH TAG
df = pd.DataFrame({'url': test, 'tags': val_list})
```

Alternatively, for a shorter call with list comprehension in place `for-loop`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'url': test,
                   'tags': [concept_val['name'] for concept_val in pred_vals]})
```